# Ubuntu made my second HDD disappear from the BIOS!

Tags: hardware, hard-drive, bios

My netbook, an ASUS 1015PX, shipped with two harddrives. After switching to Ubuntu, the second drive isn't recognized by the OS or the BIOS. I've never formatted the second drive, so it's still set up for use by Windows.

I guess I don't care about the data on the drive, I'd just like to be able to use it again. It's probably also worth mentioning that I'm very new to any form of Linux, so I'm remarkably new to the Terminal.

Comment: It maybe two partitions not two Hard drives.

Comment: @tijybba is almost certainly correct. Here is a link to the [*Asus specifications*](http://www.asus.com/Eee/Eee_PC/Eee_PC_1015PX/#specifications). Note that there is only 1 hard drive. Please open a terminal window and enter the command `sudo fdisk -l` and add the output to your question. (You can select text in terminal with your mouse and then copy the text with the keyboard shortcut: Shift+Ctrl+C )

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken. The [official specifications](http://www.asus.com/Eee/Eee_PC/Eee_PC_1015PX/#specifications) for the Asus 1015PX show that it ships with only *one* hard-drive, which can be either 250/320/500GB.

Answer (score 0):

Express Gate can be rebuilt without Windows. I have done it on a friends Asus but cannot find the link to the instructions. You basically have to create a small (5GB?) partition and copy some files to it but it is probably too complex for you to do. Anyway Ubuntu boots up fast enough not to bother using it, especially if you use the suspend function.